# Unable to connect to Windows X server from WSL Ubuntu within same computer

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, user-interface, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am doing a face recognition project and am trying to run a Python script that utilises Pillow on WSL2 Ubuntu. A minimum working code for my problem is:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("test2.png")

im.show()
```

The above code isn't running because as some of you might expect, there is no native picture viewer for WSL Ubuntu (at least not before Windows 10, which I use—more on that later). I subsequently installed ImageMagick on WSL/Ubuntu and X server on Windows as per these [instructions](https://jdhao.github.io/2019/02/16/pillow_show_image_on_wls/).

Unfortunately, this hasn't worked, giving me the error message, `unable to open display "localhost:0.0"`, and after several hours of research online for an answer, the closest I have come is this [site](https://aalonso.dev/blog/how-to-use-gui-apps-in-wsl2-forwarding-x-server-cdj), but that didn't work either, still giving me the same error message. Other solutions talk about using SSH to navigate the X server problem, but unfortunately, this really applies to connection between two different computers. I need to connect to the X server from WSL/Ubuntu to Windows within the *same* computer.

Microsoft have come up with a [solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps#fresh-install) for native picture viewers on WSL/Ubuntu, which I did follow, but again, unfortunately, it didn't work. Microsoft did say that their GUI products for WSL/Ubuntu only work with Windows 10 Build 19044+ or Windows 11, and of course, WSL2. Mine is WSL2 with Windows 10 Build **19045**, which might explain why it didn't work.

Any help with this, would be appreciated.

Comment: why not run it directly on windows? other alternatives include a virtual machine and dual boot

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution. Whilst setting the display environmental variable, instead [of](https://jdhao.github.io/2019/02/16/pillow_show_image_on_wls/):

```
echo "export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

[Do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211583/display-image-cannot-reach-x-server):

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

For some reason, the first version wasn't making the display environmental variable accessible to the GUI apps installed on WSL2/Ubuntu.